# not running npm, node or pip in vs code terminal but running in normal cmd

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am facing an issue in running environment variables in vs code terminal like npm, node(node --version) or any pip command. Node and python are installed and environement variables are set properly and commands are running in cmd but not running in vs code terminal and showing error that node is not recognized....
Tried reinstalling node, vs code still not working

Comment: Please, provide information about operational system. Repository "pip" has some dependency problem sometimes. Node and npm should not complain much in case you install it from scratch.

Comment: show the output of echoing the PATH variable in each environment.

Answer (score 0):

Run VS Code and press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `Select Default Profile`then select `Command Prompt` ,finally Press Ctrl+`